# Align items within an unordered list

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, grid

I have a problem with the alignment of items within an unordered list. The items are not perfectly aligned at the top. I have tried `display: inline-block;` and `display:inline-block;` but it wasn't successful.

Here what the alignment problem looks like:
[image: unaligned items]

This is the CSS:

```css
.licatalog li {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #3F3075;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Search">
    <ion-content class="ioncontentcatalog">
        <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Catalogo prodotti</h2>      
        <ul class="licatalog">
            <li class="row responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
                <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
                <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
                <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
                <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
                <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I tried removing the `row` class on `li` but it has not solved the problem everywhere:
[image: unaligned items without row class]

Comment: Why are you using `.row` on the `li`'s? Remove `row` from the class list on the `li` and the first issue should be fixed.

Comment: @MichaelCoker ok, I removed it, but there's another problem now. Whatch, I updated my question

Comment: Those elements are all different heights, so they don't sit like the rest do. What would you prefer happen?

Comment: I think that the problem is in: <h4 style = "color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4> because sometimes the lenght of productdesc.description is bigger. How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, that's why. **what would you prefer happen?** you can "fix" it multiple ways, but it depends on how you want the layout to change. Do you want all of them to be the same height? If you do that, there will be a different amount of blank/white space in each. Or do you want them all to be aligned at the top, but allow space at the bottom for shorter/taller elements? And do you always have rows of 3 columns or is it fluid and does it change?

Comment: Yes I want all of them to be the same height, and it is fluid and the number of columns change with the screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in top margin is because you're using `.row` on the individual `li` elements and there is `row + row` CSS in the ionic framework that alters the margin of adjacent rows. Those aren't rows, so you should remove that class from those elements.

Then to make the elements of the rows fluid, centered, and a consistent height, add `.licatalog { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center; }`

```css
.licatalog {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.licatalog li {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #3F3075;
  display: inline-block;
}
body,html {
  overflow: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.3/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="licatalog">
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description description description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} </h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
  <li class="responsive-sm" ng-repeat="productdesc in productdescs">
    <h4 style="color:#4e67c3;"> {{ productdesc.description }} productdesc productdesc</h4>
    <h4 style="color:#FF2E24;"> {{ productdesc.producer.name }}  </h4>
    <h4> [sconto per utenti registrati]  </h4>
    <h4> € {{ productdesc.price }} </h4>
    <img class="imgcatalog" src="../img/product/{{ productdesc.rootImage }}" height="130" width="100">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But how can I center the list?